# Why is only the first line of the condition executed?

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch file in which I want to do things if an operation failed. In the condition, it seems only the first lines executes for some reason...

```
call "%local_path%\unins000.exe" /verysilent
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  echo ERROR: uninstallation failed
  REM Installation failed, deletes the folder
  rmdir /s /q "%local_path%" 
  set batcherrorlevel=1
)

IF %batcherrorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %batcherrorlevel%
```

If the uninstall fails, the echo works and displays, but my exit code at the end is 0. However, if I place the line "set batcherrorlevel=1" to be the first line in the condition, the exit code is 1 but the echo does not print.

**EDIT**: I never found the real cause of the issue, but it seems it solved iself... Bothers me a little, but as long as it works, I guess it's ok...

Comment: What do you mean by "exit code"? `%batcherrorlevel%` or `errorlevel` or `%errorlevel%` or `errorlevel` when this rotine returns to its caller? You've censored out the lines that follow and don't indicate how you're executing this sequence of commands. Is this the main routine or is it `call`ed?

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous. I meant %batcherrorlevel% is 0 (it is set to 0 at the beginning of the script)

Comment: Your other code may include a loop that wraps around the sample above in which case `delayed expansion` is needed and `!batcherrorlevel!` instead of `%batcherrorlevel%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes batch file crashes when you put remarks inside a block statement

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I removed it, but it did not seem to change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to wrap it in percents, and add an == Operator.
I string-ify my comparisons, but that may just be me.

`If "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1"`

Or you could look at if using a line continuation character is needed. 
See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/06/8835317.aspx

Comment: Actually, %ERRORLEVEL% is not the same as ERRORLEVEL. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx

Comment: You are correct, but it appears to be elevated if no explicit env var was set with that name.